# How to modify a date to meet correct groovy standard?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to parse the following date in Jenkins `2021-10-14T18:12:20.578+00:00` however, I am getting the error `Unparseable date: "2020-01-01T10:10:20.578+00:00"`

This is my code, not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
Date myDate= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").parse("2020-01-01T10:10:20.578+00:00");
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Kaus, I found that my date is not formatted properly and should be `2020-01-01T10:10:20.578GMT+00:00`

I'm getting this date from some other files. I can replace + with GMT+ as follow:

```
def myDate = "2020-01-01T10:10:20.578+00:00"
myDate = myDate.replaceAll("\\+", "GMT\\+")
```

How can I do the same thing if my date is `"2020-01-01T10:10:20.578-06:00"`
The following is replacing every "-"

```
def myDate = "2020-01-01T10:10:20.578-06:00"
myDate = myDate.replaceAll("\\+", "GMT\\+").replaceAll("\\-", "GMT\\-")
```

Output: `"2020GMT-01GMT-01T10:10:20.578GMT-06:00"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `X` for ISO8601 time zone, instead of `Z` for RFC 822 time zone.

(from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```java
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

Date myDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
    .parse("2020-01-01T10:10:20.578+00:00")
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing GMT there

```
Date myDate= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").parse("2020-01-01T10:10:20.578GMT+00:00");
```

Comment: Quick question.. I am getting this date from somewhere else.. I update my OP

Comment: @Oplop98 if you arent able to change the date string its better to use X instead of Z in the date formatter.